# Selling branded products

Tags: intellectual-property, corporate-law, common-law

Legally speaking are individuals allowed to sell branded name products online, if not what are the consequences?

Answer (score 2):

### Yes

It’s called *retailing* and is a business model that has been around for a while - since the earliest civilizations at least.

Obviously such products must be genuine and legally purchased by the retailer. Some products (e.g. software) is *not* sold by the producer - it’s licensed and retailers of that have to get permission.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Yes I do believe it's called retailing, however this is rather the 'reselling' of branded name products. Due to these products being protected by Intellectual Property rights, would I not be infringing upon these if I do resell these online? According to my understanding, I may be wrong, that cyberlaw is quite different from normal law.

Comment: @user20629 so you brought say Nike shous and want to set up an online store selling them? If so, that's exactly what a bricks and mortar store does and the same laws apply. Trademark infringement applies if you try to claim that *you* made the shoes.

Comment: Yes, I see your point. If you dont claim to be the manufacturer of the shoes, is there anything substantial that say Nike or a brand manufacturer could hold against me?